# Is it possible to do my own Tkinter custom tracking variable type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I was wondering if it may be possible to create a MyValueVar type, equivalent to those like StringVar, BooleanVar, DoubleVar...

I've read Learning Python, I'm half the way of Programming Python and have almost finished Tkinter GUI Application Development Blueprints. I also google on the internet and haven't found any info about how to create such a data type.

My desire would be to create a class (it may be a mixin class) that could be attached to my visual component, and every time the visual component changes, its internal value, which is a custom class object instance, also changes. It would be ideal to have some king of MyValueVar type of variable which would be synced with the visual component.

It would be enough to me to know which class and which methods or interface I have to implement and, overall, some documentation to stick to.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it need to be a variable? Would it work just as well that whenever the visual component changes it emits an event that you can bind to? When the visual component changes, and thus the internal value changes, what then? If you create this variable and the value changes, how are you going to use that variable? In other words, "yes, it's possible". Exactly how to do it depends on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I can understand your perspective. When creating the visual component I would bind my custom variable, as you do with StringVar, for example. Then I only would have to use or pass this variable wherever it's needed.

Comment: Since you're using a binding, do you need to use a special variable? Can't the bound function directly get the value from the component? In other words, instead of `MyVariable.get` you can use use `MyComponent.get`. Why must this be a special variable when there seems to be simpler solutions?

Comment: Mmmmh. Maybe you're right and I asked this too soon before thinking deeper and may be not the the best solution. I'm going to analyze further.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments, it sounds like all you really need is a notification when the visual component changes. That can be done with virtual events.

Here's an example that updates a label when the component changes color. Every second the component will pick a random color; if it's different than the current color it will change, and send an event that the main program is listening for. When the event is detected, the label is updated.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

COLORS = ("red", "green", "yellow")
class Component(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.value = self.cget("background")
        self.after(1000, self.maybe_change)

    def maybe_change(self):
        new_color = random.choice(COLORS)
        if self.value != new_color:
            self.value = new_color
            self.configure(background=new_color)
            self.event_generate("<<ComponentChanged>>")
        self.after(1000, self.maybe_change)


class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.component = Component(self.root, width=300, height=50)
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text="")

        self.component.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.label.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

        self.component.bind("<<ComponentChanged>>",
                            self.handle_component_change)

    def handle_component_change(self, event):
        self.label.configure(text="component value is now '%s'" % self.component.value)

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

app = App()
app.start()
```